# What is the complexity of code that does O(n*log n) work, and then O(n^2) work?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm that first does something in `O(n*log(n))` time and then does something else in `O(n^2)` time. Am I correct that the total complexity would be

```
O(n*log(n) + n^2)
= O(n*(log(n) + n))
= O(n^2)
```

since `log(n) + n` is dominated by the `+ n`?

Comment: That is correct, the n² term would be dominant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is correct, as `O(n log n)` is a subset of `O(n^2)`; however, a formal proof would consist out of choosing and constructing suitable constants.

Answer (score 0):

If the call probability of both is equal then you are right. But if the probability of both is not equal you have to do an amortized analysis where you split rare expensive calls (n²) to many fast calls (n log(n)).

For quick sort for example (which generally takes n log(n), but rarly takes n²) you can proof that average running time is n log(n) because of amortized anlysis.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I take it to be about an algorithm that consists of two steps: one that runs in O(n log n) time, followed by one that runs in O(n²) time. No probabilities involved.

Comment: then answer of codor is best

Answer (score 0):

one of the rules of complexity analysis is that you must remove the terms with lower exponent or lower factors.

```
nlogn vs n^2 (divide both by n)

logn vs n
```

logn is smaller than n, than you can remove it from the complexity equation

so if the complexity is O(nlogn + n^2), when n is really big, the value of nlogn is not significant if compared to n^2, this is why you remove it and rewrite as O(n^2)